# Adjusting Values in one dataframe using balance from another dataframe in Python

Tags: python

I have two tables:

**Table A**

```
Employee ID Date    Data Used
1   01-01-2020  2
1   02-01-2020  5
1   03-01-2020  6
1   04-01-2020  4
2   05-01-2020  1
2   06-01-2020  2
2   07-01-2020  2
```

**Table B**

```
Employee ID Date    Data Balance
1   01-01-2020  6
1   02-01-2020  9
1   03-01-2020  5
1   04-01-2020  3
2   05-01-2020  7
2   06-01-2020  8
2   07-01-2020  1
```

What I am trying to do is that Table A checks in Table B how much data balance is available for an employee on a particular Date in Table A. Then create a new column in Table A say, "Adjusted" wherever enough balance is available in Table B for the adjustment, then update the column "Data Used" to 0 and update the balance in Table B so that remaining balance is available for next row in Table A.

**Working**

```
Employee ID Date    Data Used   Adjusted
1   01-01-2020  0   yes
1   02-01-2020  0   yes
1   03-01-2020  0   yes
1   04-01-2020  0   yes
2   05-01-2020  1   no
2   06-01-2020  2   no
2   07-01-2020  2   yes

Employee ID Date    Data Balance    New Balance
1   01-01-2020  6   4
1   02-01-2020  9   8
1   03-01-2020  5   7
1   04-01-2020  3   6
1   07-01-2020  7   14
1   06-01-2020  8   
1   07-01-2020  1
```

**Final Output**

```
Employee ID Date    Data Used   Adjusted
1   01-01-2020  0   yes
1   02-01-2020  0   yes
1   03-01-2020  0   yes
1   04-01-2020  0   yes
2   05-01-2020  1   no
2   06-01-2020  2   no
2   07-01-2020  2   yes
```

Thanks in advance :)

**Final Output**

```
Employee ID Date    Data Used   Adjusted
1   01-01-2020  0   yes
1   02-01-2020  0   yes
1   03-01-2020  0   yes
1   04-01-2020  0   yes
2   05-01-2020  1   no
2   06-01-2020  2   no
2   07-01-2020  2   yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to index the dataframes using two columns.

`df = df.set_index(["Employee ID","Date"])` on both dataframes should achieve this. You can now loop through one dataframe and match their indices.

To take it further, you can join both dataframes with `new_df = df1.join(df2,on=["Employee ID","Date"])` and now you have one dataframe to work with.